# Why does Vert.x create a new event loop for an http server?

Tags: java, multithreading, vert.x, event-loop

I have a very simple Vert.x application that exposes a ping endpoint:

### LauncherVerticle.java

```
public class LauncherVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> future) throws Exception {
        DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();
        options.setConfig(config());
        options.setInstances(1);

        String verticleName = Example1HttpServerVerticle.class.getName();
        vertx.deployVerticle(verticleName, options, ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                future.complete();
            } else {
                future.fail(ar.cause());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### PingVerticle.java

```
public class PingVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> future) throws Exception {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.get("/ping").handler(context -> {
            String payload = new JsonObject().put("hey", "ho").encode();
            context.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json").end(payload);
        });
    }
}
```

As expected, [by default Vert.x creates two event loop threads](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#DEFAULT_EVENT_LOOP_POOL_SIZE) that I can see with VisualVM:

[image: 2 event loop threads]

Of course, the application doesn't do anything, so I know go and add an http server to `PingVerticle`:

```
    String host = "0.0.0.0";
    int port = 7777;
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(port, host, ar -> {
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            future.complete();
        } else {
            future.fail(ar.cause());

        }
    });
```

Now I see in VisualVM that there are two new threads, an acceptor-thread, that I can more or less understand, and another eventloop-thread:

[image: 3 eventloop threads]

Why is this third eventloop-thread created?

Comment: Why not? Number of eventloop threads may be limited by specifying event loop pool size in `VertxOptions`. By default, it is 2 x **number of cores** on the machine

Answer (score 3):

According to [vert.x javadoc](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#DEFAULT_EVENT_LOOP_POOL_SIZE):

> The default number of event loop threads to be used = **2 * number of
>   cores on the machine**.

It seems, you have more than 1 core.

Comment: You're right in that. But my machine has 4 cores. Vert.x should create 8 event loop threads. Why does it decide to create a third one when it does?

Comment: Threads are created lazy. Usually, when `runOnContext` is called (for example, when new Verticle should be deployed).
You may debug `io.vertx.core.impl.VertxThreadFactory#newThread` to find out why and when each thread was created.

Answer (score 2):

Not much documentation on vert.x architecture but there is an interesting read on [Understanding Vert.x Architecture](https://www.cubrid.org/blog/understanding-vertx-architecture-part-2)

BTW, I have four core machine and i see the same number of threads at the application startup. I noticed increase in number of eventloop threads as more load is generated, while other threads remain single per vert.x process.

In short,

1. vert.x-acceptor-thread-0

   - Always there when HttpServer is created
2. vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
3. vert.x-eventloop-thread-1

   - Vert.x app starts with two eventloop threads and adds more dynamically as needed until double the number of cores i.e. 2 * cores as per documentation.
4. vert.x-blocked-thread-checker

   - Always there to detect blocking routine on eventloop for more than 2000 milliseconds.